# Can't execute a process using Process.Start() while debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, process

I'm using C# and winforms in VS2015 to work on an application. I'm trying to call executable 2 from executable 1 when the user starts the application. Executable 1 then waits for executable 2 to exit, and then exits itself. Now, when everything's built and running from compiled code, it starts up executable 2 just fine. But when I'm debugging executable 1, it won't work. Executable 1 just loads up, then closes without ever apparently launching executable 2.

The code that creates the process and starts it is below:

```
Process mainForm = new Process();
mainForm.StartInfo.FileName = locPath;
mainForm.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(locPath);
mainForm.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
mainForm.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
if (passedArguments != "") mainForm.StartInfo.Arguments = passedArguments;

mainForm.Start();

mainForm.WaitForExit();
Application.Exit();
```

The variable `locPath` contains the path to executable 2. Note that I don't need to debug executable 2, I just need to see if it is reacting to the filename stored in the variable `passedArguments`.

I've already checked our security software (CylancePROTECT), and it's not blocking anything.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or something I'm doing wrong, but as I said, it works just fine when executable 1 is built and I run that compiled code.

Comment: Do you get any error?  It might not appear as an exception in `.Start()`, you might have to check the ExitCode property.

Comment: Did you try debugging? Just to be sure

Comment: Ben, I always get exit code 0.

Comment: Nekus, this problem only happens while debugging.

Comment: Well, it seems you are launching appication #2 fine and it decides by itself to exit.  Does application #2 generate a logfile or maybe write to the Windows event log?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ben Voigt's helpful insight, I managed to figure out the problem.

Setting `mainForm.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;` was sending errors back to the first executable. For some reason, this was not a fatal error when the code was compiled, but was fatal when debugging.

So a little bit of error handling (and fixing the code that was causing the error in the second executable) later, everything's working just fine.